# sqlalchemy group_by and sum

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a `SiteStaff` table that I want to group all the staff together with the same `staffId` and add up the `holiday` column.

```
>     group =  session.query(SiteStaff, func.sum(SiteStaff.Holiday)).group_by(SiteStaff.StaffID).all()
>     
>     print group
```

The output groups the staff together but does not add the column.

Here is the sql that i am trying to mimic:

```
UPDATE Staff p, (SELECT StaffID, SUM(Holiday) as mysum
 FROM SiteStaff GROUP BY StaffID) as s

    SET p.TotalDaysHolidayAllowed = s.mysum
    WHERE p.StaffID = s.StaffID
```

Comment: you can see how sql generated, and experiment with code
print session.query(SiteStaff, func.sum(SiteStaff.Holiday)).group_by(SiteStaff.StaffID)

Answer (score 4):

It was the StaffSite part that stopped it from working. I needed to add each field in like so:

```
session.query(SiteStaff.StaffID, func.sum(SiteStaff.Holiday)).group_by(SiteStaff.StaffID).all()
```